# Sort Date/Time in Unix

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, awk

**Input**

```
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
```

**Desired Output**

```
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
```

**Code I tried**

```
 sort -t ":" -k 1 -k 2 -k 3 Input.txt | sort -t " " -k 3
```

But I am not getting desired output.

Can anyone suggest anything?

---

I wrote a code... but still problem persists...

**Code**

```
 sed 's/ 12:/00:/g' Input.txt | sort -k 1,1 -k 3,3 -k 2,2 | sed 's/00:/12:/g'
```

First change **12:43:01 AM** to **00:43:01 AM**....and then apply sort command.

Comment: What *is* the desired output?

Comment: PM before AM? Is that really desired?

Comment: @steffen according to timestamp .... (date,time,AM/PM)

Comment: A bit confused, in the input I see a row: `2012-07-24 10:13:58 PM`, and in the output I see the row changed to: `2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM`

Comment: @Jon sorry my mistake .. i edited the desired output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Convert to Epoch Seconds for Sorting

Assuming that your data is stored in /tmp/foo, you can convert the timestamp into a numerically-sortable format with GNU date. For example:

```
date -f /tmp/foo '+%s' | sort |
while read; do
    date -d "@$REPLY" "+%F %I:%M:%S %p"
done
```

This should correctly handle the sort in all cases, and especially the cases where all AM times should come before all PM times on the same date. For example, 12:01 AM is now listed before 10:00 PM.

Comment: Or skip the while loops: `date --file /tmp/foo +%s | sort | sed 's/^/@/' | date --file - "+%F %I:%M:%S %p"`. The `sed` is a bit of a wart, but *c'est la vie*.

Answer (score 3):

The strings could simply be sorted lexically except for the 12-hour times.

This solution uses the [*Schwartzian Transform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to change the key that is used to sort the strings. It just adds twelve to the hour field of any string ending with `PM` and sorts by that instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

my @sorted = map $_->[0],
sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
map { (my $dt = $_) =~ s/(\d\d)(?=:\d\d:\d\d PM)/$1+12/e; [$_, $dt] } @data;

print "$_\n" for @sorted;


__DATA__
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
```

**output**

```
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
```

---

**Update**

As steffen has pointed out, even after adjusting the hours for am/pm, midnight and midday still prevent a simple string sort from working.

This program uses the core [`Time::Piece`](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece) module to reformat the date/times in ISO 8601 format `2000-02-29T12:34:56` which *can* be sorted lexically.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

my @sorted = map $_->[0],
sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
map { [ $_, toISO8601($_) ] } @data;

sub toISO8601 {
  Time::Piece->strptime(@_, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')->datetime;
}

print "$_\n" for @sorted;

__DATA__
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
2012-08-01 01:00:00 PM
2012-08-01 12:30:00 PM
2012-08-01 12:00:00 PM
2012-08-01 11:30:00 AM
2012-08-01 01:00:00 AM
2012-08-01 12:30:00 AM
2012-08-01 12:00:00 AM
```

**output**

```
2012-07-24 10:05:08 AM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
2012-08-01 12:00:00 AM
2012-08-01 12:30:00 AM
2012-08-01 01:00:00 AM
2012-08-01 11:30:00 AM
2012-08-01 12:00:00 PM
2012-08-01 12:30:00 PM
2012-08-01 01:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Also, List::UtilsBy::nsort_by() might help you there, rather than the map/sort/map triplet.
nsort_by { Time::Piece->strptime($_,'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')->epoch } @data

Answer (score 2):

a little bit `awk`ward, I admit...

<strike>cat Input.txt | \
      awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: -]"}{if($7 == "PM") $4+=12; print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$4":"$5":"$6" "$7}'|\
      sort|\
      awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: -]"}{if($7 == "PM") $4-=12; print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$4":"$5":"$6" "$7}'</strike>

**edit:**

```
cat Input.txt |\
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: -]"}{if(length($4)==1) $4="0"$4 ;if($7 == "PM") $4+=12; else if($4 ==12)$4-=12; print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$4":"$5":"$6" "$7}'|\
sort|\
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: -]"}{if($7 == "PM") $4-=12; else if($4 ==0)$4+=12; print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$4":"$5":"$6" "$7}'
```

But it works...

explanation: I convert the time format to 24 hours using `awk`, sort it and convert it back.

**edit:** I prepend a `0` to hours with only one digit in order to get `1:0:0` and `12:0:0` sorted right. Also for AM.

Comment: but its not able to differentiate 1:42AM and 12:05AM of the same date....not able to sort that

Answer (score 2):

Using  [Schartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/lib/Date/Parse.pm) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Date::Parse;

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

my @sorted = 
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map  { [$_, str2time($_)] } @data;

say for @sorted;

__DATA__
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 01:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 12:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 01:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 12:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
```

**output:**

```
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 12:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 01:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 AM
2012-07-25 12:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 01:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
```

Comment: The comparison operator should be `<=>` because `str2time` returns a POSIX time value. For the same reason your solution won't work for dates before 1970.

Comment: @Borodin: You're right, I've changed the operator. And it doesn't work for dates before 1970 but I leave the answer for usage with dates after 1969

Answer (score 1):

12:01 AM comes before 1:01 AM, so I can't see how using just sort will help.

You need to convert to some other format, e.g. ISO 8601 or seconds since whenever to
get something that can be compared as text or numbers. A perl oneliner will do that.

Comment: Agreed, without that problem you'd do it like this: `sort -k 1,1 -k 3,3 -k 2,2 Input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/ 12:/ 00:/'| LC_ALL="C" sort -k 1,1 -k 3 | sed 's/ 00:/ 12:/'
```

It should be pretty fast solution.

Comment: Well, how about that? So it does! The `-h` option is relatively new though: I know for a fact Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) did not have it.

Comment: @ams You are right it is pretty new feature and it even doesn't work. I have make new one which definitely work.

Comment: Your new solution appears to sort by date and AM/PM, but not the time?

Comment: Incidentally, given that `-h` works so well with AM/PM, I suspect not working with 12<1 is a bug in sort.

Comment: @ams: Use `--debug` sort parameter and you will see sort is automatically adding sort by whole line as last sorting rule so it will sort by time in this last rule because key 1 (date) is already there.

Comment: @ams: In mine sort implementation `-h` doesn't sort by AM/PM in prior of time. Try `echo -e "2012-08-01 01:00:00 PM\n2012-08-01 02:00:00 AM"|sort -h` I bet it won't work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

There is my variant:

```
$sed 's|\([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\) \([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\) \([A-Z]\+\)|\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \0|' input.txt | awk '{if($7=="AM"){$7="1";if($4==12){$4 = 0}}else{$7="0"};print}' | sort -n -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 -k5 -k6 -k7 | cut -d' ' -f 8-
2012-07-24 10:05:08 PM
2012-07-24 10:13:58 AM
2012-07-24 10:57:50 AM
2012-07-24 11:15:03 AM
2012-07-24 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-25 11:26:08 PM
2012-07-26 10:13:58 AM
```

The main idea to add extra fields, sort by them and after sorted I get rid of them. Sorting numerics is simple, but to sort AM/PM I convert it to 1/0 digits to simplify sorting.

Updated: `sed` + `awk` usage may be replaced by `awk`:

```
awk -F'[-: ]' '{printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s\n", $1, $2, $3, ($4 == 12 && $7 == "AM" ? 0 : $4), $5, $6, $7 == "AM", $0)}' input.txt |
sort -n -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 -k5 -k6 -k7 |
cut -d' ' -f 8-
```

Updated: fix AM/PM issue

Comment: Hey ... i used your concept...but in other way...i changed 12:01 AM to 00:21 AM and applied the sort command and agian replaced 00 with 12.... Thanks :)

Comment: -1 because it doesn't work... `12:05:50 AM` is sorted after `11:26:08 PM`

Comment: now `10:57:50 AM` is sorted after `10:13:58 PM` ;) you're getting there. I know how it feels...

Comment: As far I understand this is what author asking?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/echo -e "$(date -d"&" +%s)\t&"/e' file | sort -n | sed 's/.*\t//'
```

or:

```
date -f file +%s | paste - file | sort -n | sed 's/\S\+\s\+//'
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I coded without using any external modules. Though its lengthy but working smoothly for any date format.

**Technique Used :**

1. First covert each date in the file to its timestamp
2. Sort the timestamp as they are in numbers.
3. Again convert the timestamp into date using scalar localtime.

**Code**

```
my @input = `cat Input.txt`;

    open (ts,">","tt.txt");
    foreach my $i (@input)
    {
            chomp($i);
            my $timestamp = `date --date "$i" +\%s`;
            chomp($timestamp);
            push (@time,$timestamp);
            print ts "$timestamp\n";
    }
    close(ts);

    open (ts,">","sort_time.txt");
    my @sorted_time = join "\n",sort {$a<=>$b} @time;
    chomp(@sorted_time);
    print ts "@sorted_time\n";
    close(ts);

    my @input1=  `cat sort_time.txt`;
    open (ts,">","sort_timestamp.txt");
    foreach my $st1 (@input1)
    {
            chomp($st1);
            my $st2 = scalar localtime($st1);
            chomp($st2);
            print ts "$st2\n";
    }
    close(ts);



    @input2 = `cat sort_timestamp.txt`;
    open (ts,">","Output.txt");
    foreach my $st2 (@input2)
    {
            chomp($st2);
            $pro_time = `date --date "$st2" +\%Y-\%m-\%d~\%r | sed 's/~/ /g'`;
            chomp($pro_time);
            print ts "$pro_time\n";
    }
    close(ts);


    `rm tt.txt sort_time.txt sort_timestamp.txt`;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you decided to reimplement the `date` utility in perl by shelling out to `date`?

Comment: This is wildly inefficient, and I see no benefit over the answers already given by CodeGnome and others. If there are restrictions in your work environment, you should post them in the original question.  As it is, most of the work in your perl code is done by going out to shell, the rest is more efficiently handled in shell as well, so why use perl at all? If this had to be done in perl, you could use one of the perfectly fine bash answers in a single use of backticks.

Comment: @chepner  I agree with you ... should have posted my restrictions ... i will take care the next time ... Thanks !!